# Hodge theory on semi-Riemannian manifolds [reference request]

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, hodge-theory

I need to learn a bit of Hodge theory on manifolds and I am looking for a reference which covers the case where the metric has arbitrary signature $(p,q)$. Most books I have found seem to focus on the Riemannian case alone.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I know some basic sheaf theory and sheaf cohomology, if that matters.

Comment: I don't know to what degree the semi-Riemannian case is salvageable, but certainly the standard approach does not work. The point is that for a Riemannian metric, the Hodge Laplacian $(d+d^*)^2$ is elliptic, but this is not at all true in the semi-Riemannian setting; an explicit calculation on $T^n$ shows that it acts on functions on $T^n$ by $\sum_{i=1}^p \partial^2/\partial x_i^2 - \sum_{j=p+1}^{p+q} \partial^2/\partial x_j^2$ which is of course not even a little elliptic. Do you have some specific reason to think that Hodge theory should work in any reasonable way?

Comment: To be honest, I have to particular reason to expect it to work. I was just hoping that some of theory might be salvageable in the case of arbitrary signature (or at the very least Lorentzian signature). If it isn't, could you recommend a good Hodge theory text for the Riemannian case (as an answer)? I would happy to accept that.

Comment: @eyes: [Here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/132924/40804) is a more authoritative denial than I can give, by someone who thinks about this sort of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am extremely skeptical that one could do Hodge theory on a semi-Riemannian manifold without *extreme* changes, because the Laplacian in signature $(p,q)$ is $\partial/\partial x_1^2 + \dots + \partial/\partial x_p^2 - \dots - \partial/\partial x_{p+q}^2$, which is not an elliptic operator, and ellipticity is completely crucial to the Hodge theory. This is probably not the only issue, but it's certainly first that comes to mind.

A great source for Hodge theory on Riemannian manifolds in the appropriate generality (elliptic complexes of differential operators on vector bundles) is Wells, Differential analysis on complex manifolds. A different approach (less general and different in flavor) can be found in both Griffiths and Harris and Warner; both are more or less the same proof.